# Rails hstore map of maps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I'm using an hstore column:

```
add_column :my_table, :entities, :hstore
```

And I store in it a map of arrays:

```
{
  likes: ['football','soccer'],
  post: [1,3]
}
```

However, when I load it from the DB, I get the array as a string and not as array:

```
info.likes 
> "['football','soccer']"
```

Is there a way to make it return as an array of strings, not as a string?

Comment: try serialize :entities in your model

Comment: This would work better with json than hstore.

Comment: @craig, could you elaborate?

Comment: @yossale Not really; I don't use Rails. My point is that if you want nested keys, storing json in the db is going to be a lot better than storing serialised Ruby objets. Especially with PostgreSQL 9.3/9.4's json/jsonb support.

Comment: (1) Please don't use `serialize`, `serialize` is an evil kludge. (2) The JSON type (supported out of the box in Rails4) will serve you better for anything beyond simple key/value storage.